# Images are gone with membergroup

Tags: custom-fields, image

If i create a new membergroup, based on the users membergroup. All the images from a custom field are not showing. If i switch the user to the default membergroup, it works again.
users that are not logged in, can see the images.

So basicly, if i move a user to a new membergroup (based on the default "member" group), all the images from custom fields are not showing.

Do i miss something, or is it a configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, very weird but also understandable. I had to give permissions in the File Upload Perferences.

Its odd because the membergroup "members" is allowed and for a new membergroup that is based on that group need to give permission. Also i was thinking that those permissions where for writing only...

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically give permissions to the new membergroup in the File Upload Preferences for each upload destination, if these destinations were created before the new membergroup was created.